# getSupportFragmentManager is not recognized

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

As shown below in the code, the `MainActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, and `TabsPagerAdapter` extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

I do not know why eclipse does not recognize this line

```
viewPager = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this.fragList);
```

**MainActivity**:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.example.settingsviewpagertabs.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
....
....
....
viewPager = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this.fragList); //eclipse does not accept it
```

**adapter**:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> mFragList;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> mFragList) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mFragList = mFragList;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.get(arg0);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.size();
}
```

}

**Update_1**:

now i am usinf the below imports,

and when i use the

```
viewPager = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this.fragList);
```

i receive the below message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from TabsPagerAdapter to ViewPager
```

the imports i currently use are:

**MainActivity**:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

**adapter imports**:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

Comment: Doesn't recognize means? What does it say?

Comment: Hi, assuming you did included the support-v4 library correctly, i would simply advise you to clean your project

Comment: Probably not a solution, but you should import the support classes of `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not importing the right classes (the support ones).  Change:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

to in MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not the problem with support fragment manager. It's the problem with your `fragment list`:
look at your `tabs` adapter, you import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. However, in your `FragmentActivity`, you import `import android.app.Fragment;`. 
--> solution is change your import in `FragmentActivity`.